# printing bad video files with xargs

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, xargs

I use

```
find . -name "*.mp4" -print0 | xargs -0 -I $ bash -c "ffmpeg -v error -xerror -i $ -f null - || echo $"
```

to go over a directory and print bad video files (as ffmpeg sees it)

if I run it in a directory with only mp4 files, it will print the name of file - but, if I run it on the parent folder (a folder with many folders, each has mp4 files) I only get `$` being echoed

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `find . -name "*.mp4" -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} bash -c 'ffmpeg -v error -xerror -i "$1" -f null - || echo "$1"' _ {}` Also do you mean a literal `$` is printed or the value inside it?

Comment: Just the char itself, $, is printed instead of the file path

Comment: @123 seems to be working thanks! can you explain why?

Answer (score 0):

With GNU Parallel it looks like this:

```
find . -name "*.mp4" -print0 |
  parallel -0 "ffmpeg -v error -xerror -i {} -f null - || echo {}"
```

It is tested with filename containing ', " and space.